# Downloading Windows 10 virtual machine always fails

Tags: windows-10, disk-usage, downloads, tmp

I want to download a virtual image of Windows 10 but each time I do it it fails as can be seen on this screenshot:

[image: image shown in download list marked Failed]

My guess is that my `tmp` folder is too small. **What can I do to be able to download it properly ?**

The output of `df -h /tmp̀` is:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        19G   14G  3,5G  80% /
```

Answer (score 2):

`wget` is a good program to use to download large files from websites that have a habit of timing out before the download is completed, because it has an option to resume downloads if they are interrupted without losing the part of the file that has already been downloaded.

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads/  
wget -c https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/VMBuild_20150916/VirtualBox/IE10/IE10.Win7.VirtualBox.zip
```

The incomplete part of the download will be saved in the current directory ( `/home/your-username/Downloads` ) until the download is finished.

The `-c` option of `wget` will automatically **c**ontinue the download from the same place that it was paused if the download is interrupted. Even if the download is stopped completely, changing directories with `cd` to the same directory where the download was started the first time, and running `wget -c https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/VMBuild_20150916/VirtualBox/IE10/IE10.Win7.VirtualBox.zip` again will resume the uncompleted download from the same place where it left off.